# Jquery Type error : id is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

This is the script i m using but it is giving me error Type Error: x is null.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function()
    {
      if (entityId != null && entityId != "")
      {
        var x=document.getElementById("my_act");
        alert(x.innerHTML);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with `my_act` as ID

Comment: `getElementById("my_act");` likely doesn't exist.

Comment: the problem is either there is no element with id `my_act` or your script is executed before the element is loaded to the dom

Comment: Is `my_act` element is rendered/available in DOM?

Comment: yes id my_act is in my code <div class="name" style="display:none;" id="
my_act"><a href="https://checkout.netsuite.com/app/center/nlvisitor.nl/c.3727898/sc.6/.f?ext=F">MY ACCOUNT</a></div>

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with an ID of `my_act` on the page when this script is run.

Also, if you are using jQuery why not actually use jQuery and do `$("#my_act")` instead of `document.getElementById("my_act")`

Comment: Not at runtime. Is your script in the `<head>` section and being run before the dom has loaded?  Thats my guess