# How Display a div using jquery when user login?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display my account only when user login into website and i am creating this into netsuite here is my account section html code

```
<div class="name" style="display:none;" id="
my_act"><a href="https://checkout.netsuite.com/app/center/nlvisitor.nl/c.3727898/sc.6/.f?          ext=F">MY ACCOUNT</a></div>
```

I m using this script but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function()
{
  if (entityId != null && entityId != "")
  {
    $j('#my_act').css('display','block');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Type error : id is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006036/jquery-type-error-id-is-null)

Comment: how to resolve it please i am new to jquery and js

Comment: i tried to alert the value of entityId but its giving me error id is null

Answer (score 0):

I would say try putting an alert in the if loop to check whether the element exists at the time when the script is run.

Possibly, the script is gettig executed prior to the element actually getting loaded in the DOM.

Comment: i have wrote the script in footer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't properly manage logins with javascript/jQuery alone.  Logins are best managed with a back-end language, like PHP or ASP/.Net. This is because it is the server that must determine if someone has logged in, not their own browser.

I will use PHP as the server language for this example.

A great tool for keeping track of whether someone has been authenticated is PHP $_SESSIONs

```
<?php

    session_start();

    mysql_connect('localhost','my_cpanel_login_ID','my_cpanel_password') or die($connect_error); //or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('cpanelLoginID_dbname') or die($connect_error);

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])===true) {
        echo '<div id="my_act">Here is the information from their account</div>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="#" id="Login">Login</a>';
    }
```

---

Here are some online video tutorials that may help:

1. PHPAcademy.org - used to be free, but is now just low-priced
   [Registration and Login tutorial](https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system)
   [PHP and MySQL with PDO and mysqli_](https://phpacademy.org/videos/php-and-mysql-with-mysqli)
2. TheNewBoston.com -- try this one:
   [Project Lisa - Unfinished tutorial but very good](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=51)
   [Intro to PHP](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11)
   [Intro to jQuery](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)

Comment: im using netsuite to implement this and on the basis of customer id only we can identify if someone logged in or not...i have stored customer id in entityId.

Comment: That was a rather critical piece of info missing from your question. Sameer (below) has a good suggestion: put a js alert() at the top of your if{} block so that if entityId has a value at least you will know that is working...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $j("#my_act").show();
}
)
;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="name" style="display:none" id="my_act"><a 

href="http://google.com">MY ACCOUNT</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just an extended comment with some things (untested) for you to try:

Since entity has a value, you can try checking the length of the entityId. First, begin with an alert:

```
alert(entityId.length);
```

to ensure it does what we desire.

Then, something like:

```
if (entityId.length > 0) {
    $j('#my_act').css('display','block');
}
```

BTW, are you sure that your `jQuery.noConflict();` code is working correctly?  Try something simple (without any if statements to add any additional layers of complexity):

```
 $j('#my_act').css({'color':'red','font-size':'bold'});
```

Does that work?

Comment: Okay, did the first test (up top) work? That is, what value did you get when you alerted entityId.length?